# Optimizing Code Used to Convolve Image

Tags: c, optimization, convolution

The following code is used to convolve an image.  Each pixel of said image is represented by the following:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short red; /* R value */
    unsigned short green; /* G value */
    unsigned short blue; /* B value */
} pixel;
```

As can be seen, RGB values have 16-bit representations (“16-bit color”). An image I is stored as a one-dimensional array of pixels, where the (i, j)th pixel is I[RIDX(i,j,n)]. Here n is the dimension of the image matrix, and
RIDX is a macro defined as follows

```
#define RIDX(i,j,n) ((i)*(n)+(j))
```

You can think of I[RIDX(i,j,n)] as equivalent to I[i][j] for most purposes.  At the end of this I need to optimize the below code using techniques like code motion, loop unrolling, and blocking.

```
char naive_convolve_descr[] = "naive_convolve: Naive baseline implementation";
void naive_convolve(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst)
{
    int i, j, ii, jj, curI, curJ;
    pixel_sum ps;

    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++){
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++){
            ps.red    = 0.0;
            ps.green  = 0.0;
            ps.blue   = 0.0;
            ps.weight = 0.0;
            for (jj = -2; jj <= 2; jj++){
                for (ii = -2; ii <= 2; ii++){
                    curJ = j+jj;
                    if(curJ<0 || curJ>=dim){
                        continue;
                    }
                    curI = i+ii;
                    if(curI<0 || curI>=dim){
                        continue;
                    }
                    ps.red   += src[RIDX(curI, curJ, dim)].red *   kernel[ii+2][jj+2];
                    ps.green += src[RIDX(curI, curJ, dim)].green * kernel[ii+2][jj+2];
                    ps.blue  += src[RIDX(curI, curJ, dim)].blue *  kernel[ii+2][jj+2];
                    ps.weight += kernel[ii+2][jj+2];
                }
            }
            dst[RIDX(i,j,dim)].red   = (unsigned short)(ps.red/ps.weight);
            dst[RIDX(i,j,dim)].green = (unsigned short)(ps.green/ps.weight);
            dst[RIDX(i,j,dim)].blue  = (unsigned short)(ps.blue/ps.weight);
        }
    }
}
```

My kernel is

```
//emboss top-right kernel
Kernel emboss_tr_kernel = 
{
    {0.0,  -1.0, -1.0,   -1.0,  -1.0},
    {1.0,   0.0, -4.0,  -16.0,  -1.0},
    {1.0,   4.0,  1.0,   -4.0,  -1.0},
    {1.0,  16.0,  4.0,    0.0,  -1.0},
    {1.0,   1.0,  1.0,    1.0,   0.0}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Too big for a comment, so I'm posting as an answer.

Actually, you'll probably get the most speedup by changing your order of your two outer loops. Your inner loop iterates over `i`. But `src[RIDX(curI, curJ, dim)]` expands to `((curI)*(dim)+(curJ))`. So every 2 successive `curI`s are `dim` pixels away from each other in memory. So you will be generating lots of cache misses your way -- iterating over the columns.
Iterate over the rows instead.

Next consider moving the pieces of code only relevant to the the `jj` loop to it's loop and not the innermost loop. As in:

```
for (jj = -2; jj <= 2; jj++){
    curJ = j+jj;
    if(curJ<0 || curJ>=dim){
        continue;
    }
```

Instead you could also use

```
for(curJ=max(0, j-2); curJ <= min(dim-1, j+2); ++curJ)
```

Next see if you can decompose your kernel linearly separable kernels. And if so, rewrite the code to take advantage of it. (Edited: I don't think this is possible as your matrix has full rank.)

Then finally consider if you can parallelize the code. But be careful not to do so in a manner than would cause multiple threads to share the same cache line. 
http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206

Answer (score 0):

There are several opportunities for optimization.

### Generic optimizations

- removing conditions out from the inner loop

  - option 1 -- make a different inner loop for all 9 segments
  - option 2 -- copy the src buffer to a temporary buffer with pre-cleared border
- after choosing option 2, deinterleave the data in single plane e.g.

  ```
  rows -2, -1: all zeroes
  rows 0..dim-1: [0 0][green][0 0 0 0][red][0 0 0 0][blue][0 0]
  rows dim, dim+1: all zeroes
  ```

  - This allows better chances for automatic SIMD optimizations
  - Vertical planarization works too...
- Strength reduction of "sum+=weight" is constant (is it 1 by mistake?) -- no need to calculate it every time
- Strength reduce the src pointer calculation in the inner loop to (src += dim_padded;)
- Go for manual SIMD vectorization using intrinsics

  - Pad width to multiple of 4 (+4) and discard the unneeded results
  - Load 5 registers per every 4 samples, then convolve with 4 shifted versions of the kernel
  - Operating from registers only relaxes the memory bandwidth and cache misses

### Kernel specific optimizations

1) Write out the expression using the constants +-{1,4,16} as integers

- the compiler can use the optimal instructions for multiplication
- no conversion to float and back
- add/subtract first, multiply later (only 2 multiplications per kernel)

2)
The kernel has runs of ones in two dimensions sharing sums with nearby cells:

```
  [0 h h h h]
  [         ]
  [         ]
  [         ]
[0[h h h h] ]   <-- here the sum `h+h+h+h` is shared between the two
[V - d - v]         positions.
[V D - d v]
[V - D - v]
[H H H H -]
```

Here `Sum(v)[row][column_X] == -Sum(v)[row][column_X + 4]` and `Sum(H)[row][column] == -Sum(h)[row + 4][column - 1]`

Thus one can ease the calculation (and memory bandwidth) a bit, by calculating Vertical and Horizontal sums of 3 and 4 elements into temporary arrays.

Then the inner loop needs to access just 11 items. Similar case can be utilized for the diagonal sums `d = -D` which may have diminishing returns for the investment.